# How to make Api.ai audio and a dynamic UI with voiceover not interfere with each other

Tags: user-interface, mobile, accessibility, voiceover, dialogflow-es

[Edited question] If I have an api.ai discussion app which dynamically creates buttons with the intent names on them: Say I ordered a sandwich and now api.ai is asking me what spread I want, but, ALSO at the same time CHANGES THE UI and SHOWS me the options: Mayo, Mustard, Ketchup as checkbox-buttons to press. This app will be specific for a visually impaired but not totally blind person using this, who has VoiceOver set up for accessibility.

They now see:

```
Dressings                 Salads
[ ] Mayo     $2.40        [ ] Tuna      $11.50      
[ ] Mustard  $0.85        [ ] Olives     $4.60    
[ ] Ketchup  $8.19        [ ] Anchovies $99.99
```

The voice-over will automatically say:

```
Dressings: Checkbox mayo dollars 2.40, 
checkbox mustard dollars zero point 85, checkbox ketchup....
```

I do not want to hear that message, but rather the API.AI reply which would talk in "natural language discussional speak":

```
"Do you want anything added? We have salads and dressings..."
```

I don't want the voice-over and app.ai to interfere with each other. What do I do? Any thoughts? How do I temporarily disable the voice-over?

Important: If the semi-blind user momentarily leaves my app and goes to another app, or chooses my app's settings page, the voice-over should work as usual. Only while in this certain screen I want the voice-over disabled, and the API.AI to take over. Can this be done programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as you click on the option, it says the option. So then they know what they've pressed. If you're worried about it overlapping the audio if you press two different options at nearly the same time, you could try to cut the audio short if there is a choice in different options .

Comment: If you would reword your answer to be more precise and less "suggestion like" it probably would read like an answer, and not like a comment.

Comment: Thank you Leanne. But as far as I understand, Voice-Over automatically reads me the whole screen when it changes. No?  I'll clarify the question even more.